# express js:Express session undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I have created project using express-generator and installed express-session package.

Here is the order of express-session

**app.js**

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'my-app/dist')));

app.use(expressSession({ resave: true ,secret: '123456' , saveUninitialized: true}));

//routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/passport', index);
app.use('/api', users);
```

in my **routes/index.js** i am setting a session value

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

    req.session.test = 'some data';
    console.log("Session value",req.session.test);
   res.send('ok);

});
```

in another route i am getting that session value

```
router.get('/me',function(req,res){
    console.log('session value',req.session.test);
    res.send('hello');
});
```

But here  i am getting undefined value for this `req.session.test`

express version:~4.15.5

Here is my app.js full version https://pastebin.com/2wPm5bTw

Answer (score 0):

I think the session value test is never sent back to the client because you didn't add `res.send()` to your `/login` POST handler.

I added that to [this example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spangle-kayak) and it works fine (you can check the logs by pressing the button in the top left).

Comment: Still i have same error  res.send already present it missing in question bcz of a typo

Comment: If you look at the example you can see it uses your code and works as expected. You should really explain what you're doing and where it goes wrong more thoroughly. Also you could give us a git repo so we can test it out for ourselves.

Comment: I tried with a fresh project in that session works properly

Answer (score 0):

Complete `Request` by `res.end()`.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

    req.session.test = 'some data';
    console.log("Session value",req.session.test);
    res.send();
});
```

Comment: Still i have same error  res.send already present it missing in question bcz of a typo